# Distinct multiselect query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm making a multiselect filter in Laravel 6 for the index function. As you can deduct, there is a pivot table between news and jobCategory so I need a join to use the whereIn to show the news that the user filter. 
The issue is that the distinct() doesn't work, therefore I get repeated results when I don't want that. Someone knows where i'm wrong.

```
    $query = News::distinct()->with('newsTranslations');

    if ($request->has('categories')) {
        $query = $query->whereIn('news.idCategory', $input['categories']);
    }

    if ($request->has('jobCategories')) {
        $query = $query->join('jobCategories_News','news.id','=','jobCategories_News.idNews')
        ->whereIn('jobCategories_News.idjobCategories', $input['jobCategories']);
    }
    $query = $query->distinct('news.id')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: I think you should use the select() method to indicate to which column the distinct() should be applied. Something like `$query->select('news.id')->distinct()`

Comment: Can't do that, because I need the whole object to access to the relationships.

Comment: Well I fixed using what porloscerros said. Thanks a bunch mate

Comment: Oh, just now I'm connecting and I see your messages.  Good to know you solved it, if you post an answer explaining how you did it, it can serve others with same problem (and you'll have my upvote too)